# PHP variable assignment causing page crash

Tags: php

I'm having an issue with some PHP code where my page is crashing whenever i insert the following code.

*Revised Code*

```
 $supp = emb_meta( "_emb_supplier" ); 

if ($supp == "Type1") {
    echo '<a href="http://link.com/" target="_blank">Text here for Type1! product.</a>';
} 
elseif ($supp == "Type2") {
    echo '<a href="http://link.com/" target="_blank">Text here for Type2 product.</a>';
}
elseif ($supp == "Type3") {
    echo '<a href="http://link.com/" target="_blank">Text here for Type3 product.</a>';
}
elseif ($supp == "Type4"){
    echo '<a href="http://link.com/" target="_blank">Text here for Type4 product.</a>';
}
else {
    echo '';
}
?>
```

Comment: Is there an error appearing?If so, what does it say?

Comment: The whole page doesn't render unfortunately. I was wondering if my variables are not working correctly.

Comment: Instead of `$supp = emb_meta( "_emb_supplier" );` just set `$supp = "Type1";` and see what happens. Maybe `emb_meta` is unknown here

Answer (score 1):

```
elseif {$supp == "Type4"
```

This syntactically incorrect. It should be:

```
elseif ($supp == "Type4"){
```

Also you should add a `;` behind each `echo` statement, although I guess this won't be the problem here

Comment: Thanks that is incorrect but still getting the error after the correction.

Comment: Did you add the `;`? Maybe you update your question to the current code that still won't work

Answer (score 0):

Haven't programmed in PHP for ages.  But I think you're missing some semicolons there.

I'm like 50% sure.

It's possible you don't need a semi-colon cause it is the last operation, but try adding semicolons to your if blocks.

Comment: The semicolon won't be the issue. There is a mistake in the syntax at "Type4"

Comment: I see. I agree.  The syntax error there is definitely the culprit.  How would you recommend people normally debug a "page won't load" error?  If they tried running it from the command line would they get a message about the syntax error?  I suppose maybe apache logs might show info too.

Comment: Correct, there is. In the error log you would see what is the issue. Sometimes you find a special php error log in /var/log

Comment: I also recomend to never use "==" operator. It complitly broken in php. Use "===" instead.

Comment: Ok the issue is with that first expression. I tried changing the expression $supp = emb_meta( "_emb_supplier" ); to $supp = "Type1"; and everything worked to perfection! The issue now is to determine why that first expression isn't transferring to the variable correctly.

Answer (score 0):

please put `;` after each statement and correct `elseif($supp == "Type4")`

```
    $supp = emb_meta( "_emb_supplier" ); 

    if ($supp == "Type1") {
        echo '<a href="http://l...content-available-to-author-only...k.com/" target="_blank">Text here for Type1! product.</a>';
    } 
    elseif ($supp == "Type2") {
        echo '<a href="http://l...content-available-to-author-only...k.com/" target="_blank">Text here for Type2 product.</a>';
    }
    elseif ($supp == "Type3") {
        echo '<a href="http://l...content-available-to-author-only...k.com/" target="_blank">Text here for Type3 product.</a>';
    }
    elseif ($supp == "Type4"){

        echo '<a href="http://l...content-available-to-author-only...k.com/" target="_blank">Text here for Type4 product.</a>';
    }
    else {
        echo '';
    }
```

Comment: Tried the code update but still getting nothing else rendering on the page.

Comment: use `$supp = "Type1";` instead of `$supp = emb_meta( "_emb_supplier" ); 
` and see what happend

Comment: Yes i tried that and the rest of the code works perfectly. the issue is that equating the variable to emb_meta isn't working and i'm not sure why.